# Create a custom right-click menu item in LabVIEW Project Explorer

Tags: labview

When we right click a folder or Virtual folder we will get a drop down menu. From that when we select New we will get another drop down menu consisting of VI, class, Virtual folder and so on. I want to add a custom menu to this list. Is it possible?

[image]

Comment: What item do you want to add to this menu and what do you want to happen when your custom item is selected?

Comment: I want to add a class with some VIs already on it.But we should be able to name the class.

Answer (score 1):

Customizations in the project window can be done using project providers - https://decibel.ni.com/content/docs/DOC-21802 . I'm not sure if this can do the specific things you want.

Note that this is not officially exposed and apparently you need to get NI to give you access, or you can try something like this - https://lavag.org/topic/18545-i-have-taken-the-first-step-towards-unofficially-opening-up-the-project-provider-framework/#comment-111305

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to add new items, it's probably a lot simpler to add a menu item under the Tools menu. That's fully documented AND supported by NI. There are so many strange rules and odd situations with providers (because they have to accommodate a truly dizzying array of things already plugging in), it's probably best to avoid them.

To add something to the Tools menu, just put a VI in the "project" subdirectory of your LV install. If you invoke it from a VI that is in a particular application instance, you will even get the right application instance to do your "Add New Lib & Rename" in.